# Multiwire branch circuit means of disconnect

Tags: electrical, wiring, detached-structure

I am planning on running a multiwire branch circuit to my detached garage as described [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/48408/wiring-to-a-detached-garage). I have one question though on the means of disconnect for a multiwire branch circuit. Do I need a special type of disconnect because it is a multiwire branch circuit? Would something like [this Eaton 60A Outdoor Air Conditioner Disconnect](http://www.menards.com/main/electrical/circuit-protection-distribution/safety-switches-disconnects/eaton-60a-outdoor-disconnect/p-1444429555748-c-6435.htm?tid=-7774005053886350991) be adequate?

[image: picture]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "means of disconnect" requirement for multi-wire branch circuits (NEC 210.4b) simply requires that there be a means of disconnect, and it disconnect all legs at once.  Usually, that is simply the 2-pole (240v) circuit breaker in the panel, and that is fine; that completes the requirement.

Unrelated to the MWBC is a separate requirement that power entering an outbuilding.  It must have a disconnecting means of some kind (NEC 225.31) near where the power enters, inside or out (225.32). That's where you use a disconnect switch like the above.  There is no need to disconnect the neutral.

I would point out that if you're doing a sub-panel, simply use a panel that has a "main" breaker and that's your shut-off switch. It's legit to have a 30A run to a sub-panel and have a 200A main breaker in the sub-panel.  The big breaker just serves as an obvious shutoff switch (and GFCI if it does that).

Answer (score -1):

As long as the breaker feeding the circuit is a double pole you should be fine because both will disconnect the ungrounded conductors simultaneously, in the case of a fault both will be opened. NEC 2014 210.4.B